# Was the peak of the NBA aka popularity of basketball in 90's ( or including 80's ) "as I consider" or just my "Old days were good"?

Tags: sports

I always wonder and argue with young boys in my country if today's so called superstar [**Lebron James**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeBron_James) remained nothing but a role player had he played in 90's or the 80's because back then there was even a time there was no [**flagrant foul**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagrant_foul) and there was even an [**illegal defense**](http://www.celticshub.com/2017/09/20/celticshub-whiteboard-illegal-defense-shapes-nba/) and in my opinion, there is no need to mention that [**Micael Jordan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan) was the Greatest Of All Time. The boys here argue Michael was nobody but an old guy, today's players are muscular than the players in 80's and 90's and well scientifically trained, so on and so forth. What is the general reaction in today's U.S about this?

### What I would like to hear is the general air towards the sport, basketball ( if possible toward the NBA too ), compared with the general air in 80's and 90's. Did it decline in the homeland, which is the U.S?

Data the [**NBA's TV final audience ratings.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Finals_television_ratings)

[image]

---

Since user @JonCuster started talking about the American football, here is the [**Super Bowl television ratings.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_television_ratings) ( I know that the most popular sports in the U.S is the American football. )

Per his claim, the number of TV audience on Super Bowl is **rising,** contrary to that of the NBA.

[image]

If someone shows me the data, and if it's reasonable, I would like to "surrender", otherwise I will hold mine. ( Who wouldn't watch the **NBA Finals, which decides the championship of the year,** if they are the NBA fans. )

P.S 1 I didn't know if there was a sports SE in SE so please migrate should moderators consider if this question belongs there. Sorry.

P.S2 Considering the simultaneous downvote right after asking at Sports SE, I can't expect any reasonable answer from there, I think. So let me ask here kindly. Thanks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: P.S I would like to use the answer as the supplement data when next time I will argue with young lads in my country like a child:). Thank you.

Comment: P.S2 Seriously, I will move this question to sports SE since this question might better   fit there. ( I really didn't know that ). Honestly, I just remain the question here so that I will not lose the upvote. Sorry.

Comment: P.S 3 I moved this question to Sports SE. I would like to delete this question within 2-3 days if any answer does not come.

Comment: Given that viewer numbers have changed for all sports over the last 40 years because of large changes to viewing options, using that data is problematic at best.

Comment: @JonCuster So could you show me the "counter" data? Then if it is reasonable, "I will surrender". ^^

Comment: Super bowl viewers have been generally rising over the time frame (total viewers vs share can confuse matters). World Series is flat but pretty variable (highest shares were back in the late 1970s to 1980). Data available on Wiki. The move of lots of playoff games to cable has not helped mass audiences, as has the proliferation of channels and Netflix.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not asking about American football or neither the succor. Will you make an answer instead please?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Exactly, But today's people put Lebron James at the NO.2 of the 50 greatest players in the NBA history, forgetting about what Magic Johnson and Larry Bird achieved and contributed in 80's. This is almost a blaspheme to me.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Exactly. His net asset is worth 1.5 billions, and Nike is still updating the Air Jordan shoes year by year. But today's kids, even our country's boys who are now living in the U.S put Lebron at such a high position. I'm old, at 40's, O.K, but don't forget about how touch 80's and 90's NBA were. ( And probably its influence on the basketball in general as a sports. )

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Oh thanks. I will wait for 2 or 3 days to see what might come. If nothing comes, I will delete, I promise.

Comment: Why would you do that? IMO self-answer the question with a few references... It's not a bad question, nor is it an obvious one without remembering those days. Just, anyone who reads the intro of Jordan's page can reasonably come to the conclusion that a) he really was super well marketed, and because of that, b) he really drove the popularity of basketball all by himself. As I wrote in an earlier comment, the audience peaks in your chart correspond to when Jordan was playing.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Oh OK. Thank you for kind advice (m_m).